# PrimeReact in combination with react-icons

Tags: reactjs, primereact, react-icons

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to use the icons from the react-icons package in PrimeReact, since the primeIcons package unfortunately does not contain all the icons I need for my project.

I haven't found a solution for this, because react-icons exports the icons as components and PrimeReact gets the icons assigned by string.

Comment: I don't know about React Icons but I use FontAwesome Icons in my PrimeReact project no problem.  PrimeReact has full support for FontAwesome.

Comment: @Melloware Thanks for your comment, it works now, i simply needed to use it as an inside element and not as a class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change say **search** icon in a button

you can access https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/search?q=fasearch

right click on the icon and inspect the elements, copy the SVG for the same from the developer console
create say **search.svg** file and paste the svg for **fasearch** in the file
add below class in say **root.css** file

```
.pi-search:before {
  content: url(search.svg) !important;
}
```

This will change the search icon

Comment: This is a nice approach, never thought about that!
Thankl you for showing it!

Comment: there is one limitation in this approach.. since url(..) function converts the svg to image, I am facing issues in adding theme specific colour to the icon. e.g. light colour for the icon if the background is dark and vice-versa... If you can find some solution for that plz let me know :)

Comment: If I find out anything I will let you know of course!

Answer (score 1):

This is a example

```
import { FaWheelchair, FaBolt, FaCarAlt, FaCar } from "react-icons/fa";
```

...

```
return( 
<div className="flex card-container overflow-hidden ">
              <div className="flex-none flex align-items-center justify-content-center  p-1">
                            <TfiWheelchair />
                            <p className="text-lg">Wheelchair</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>);
```